# How to get access to SIM Card for getting my nearest tower location from iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

anyone Know How to get access to SIM Card for getting my nearest tower location from iPhone SDK or if exist a framework for doing it other than  GPS(Corelocation).

Comment: No way to do that. But why dont you want to use core location???

Answer (score 0):

CoreLocation will first use assisted GPS for its location. Assisted GPS is will start with the triangulation of cell towers. So if you do not set accuracy to high and you will get the location based in on cell tower triangulation.